# A JavaScript exception occurred while highlighting text in WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, exception, wkwebview

While trying to highlight text in WKWebview using JS files, it's keep on failing and showing the below log.

> Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception
>   occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0,
>   **WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError**: **undefined is not a function**,
>   WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, NSLocalizedDescription=A
>   JavaScript exception occurred})

In `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` I'd added below lines

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(0.3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) {() -> Void in

            webView.evaluateJavaScript("uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(\"a\")", completionHandler: { (returnVal: Any?, error: Error?) -> Void in
               print(error)

            })
        }
```

It's not highlighting the text. What am I missing here?

`function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(keyword)` is there in the js file

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is, Userscript wasn't added properly.

```
let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
userContentController.add(messageHandler, name: "jsBridge")
let audioString = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "GetAudioLinks", withExtension: "js", subdirectory:"/Assets/js/" )

let audioStringScript = WKUserScript(source: audioString, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
userContentController.addUserScript(audioStringScript)
```

now, it's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("this.uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(\"a\");"...
```

just adding `this.` and `;` at the end of js code

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,+1. issue is a different one